# Set Variable after Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onload

Once my page load a unique link is generated through a third party application, I need that stored in a variable to be accessed later.

How do I set the link as a variable, **AND** how do I make sure it is done AFTER the page has been loaded?

Code generated by third party application:

```
<div class="_ohe lfloat"><a href="THE LINK TO BE SET GENERATES HERE" src=".jpg" target="_blank" class="img _8o _8s UFIImageBlockImage"><img class="_1ci img" src="https://scontent.ftpa1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p48x48/12472831_1760775617477649_5525707532693192482_n.jpg?oh=32736fd5787e04e6f55aa8eb7ecaa529&amp;oe=59539C06" alt=""></a></div>
```

Comment: You could create an ajax call that will inform your server the generated link using window.onLoad or jquery $(function(){ajax call}), the server should store it in a session variable for later use.

Comment: The ajax function isn't very intuitive, that was the original idea but I seem to lack the brain capacity. I am actively looking at ajax, not giving up, but was hoping for a better option.

Comment: @PauloLima: How could Ajax be usefull on this?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette he/she tagged php on this question, so i assume he'll be needing this variable on a server for later use, your answer suffice if its only JavaScript he needs

Comment: @PauloLima: Never "assume", read the question and ask more details. I removed the PHP tag which was irrelevant.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette i'm just tried to help, and since the user who asked the question have also considered using ajax maybe i'm not wrong, but I understand your concern, i did read the question, just had another understanding of the goal intended

Answer (score 2):

To store the `href` of a link in a variable after page load:

**EDIT**: Add an interval to get the value if it is appended slightly after load.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var myHref = "";

  // Set an interval to check cyclically for the presence of href
  var waitForTheHref = setInterval(function(){

    // Look for the value
    myHref = $(document).find("._ohe.lfloat a").attr("href");

    // Check if the value is present
    if( myHref !== "" && myHref !== "undefined"){

      // Show it in console
      console.log(myHref);

      // You have the value... Clear the interval!
      clearInterval(waitForTheHref);
    }

  },50);  // milliseconds.
});
```

Comment: The variable isn't showing up in console, but when I set the variable to a numeric equation the solution shows up fine. I assume it is because the third party application loads a bit slower, however I thought strings like "onLoad" wait until all elements have successfully been loaded.

Would it be wise to add a "Sleep" per say or is there another solution?

Comment: The only thing that may not be loaded when the `load` event occurs are images. But a `setTimeout()` may be tryied if the `href` is appended by a client-side script. I will edit.

Comment: So I used an `setInterval()` instead, since you don't know what is the delay... This will check for the value each 50ms until it finds it. Assuming the HTML in appended by a script which hasn't ran (or finished running) when the `load` event occurs.

Comment: What is the image? Is it an image that you select to upload ? I need more detail on what triggers those element creation.

Comment: I have added you on skype. Thank you for your help.